# Bessel Functions of Half-Integer Order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

I recently came across the general form of Bessel Functions of half-integer order given by:
$$
J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)=(-1)^n\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left(x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{\sin{x}}{x}.
$$
I am required to prove this using the recurrence relation:
$$
J_{s\pm 1}(x)=\frac{s}{x}J_s(x)\mp J'_s(x).
$$
I tried to prove by induction, but I think my main issue is that I am not sure what $\left(x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ actually means. I was thinking that the power $n$ is distributed across to $x^{-1}$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ but that gives $x^{-n}$ which allows me to simplify the general form to be 
$$
J_{n+\frac{1}{2}}(x)=(-1)^n\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}x^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}.
$$
If that is indeed true, textbooks should have presented this formula instead. I have used MATLAB to help me find the zeros using 2 different methods (the formula above, and by besselj) but gave me different answers. That is how I know that my simplification is wrong.

Could anyone kindly enlighten me what $\left(x^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$ means and how I can go about proving the general form using the recurrence relations?
Any form of help is deeply appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you differentiate with regard to *x*, and then divide by *x*, and then repeat the entire process $($by repeatedly applying these two operations, in this exact order$)$, a total number of *n* times.